# How do use navigator.push to navigate to a specific tab

Tags: flutter

Let's assume I want to navigate to a specific tab, for example to the tab 'Chats' which view is defined in ChatsOverview(). Each tab does not have its own Scaffold / Material widget. It directly returns a StreamBuilder, so navigator.push is not directly working?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              leading: Container(), 
              flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                  child: new TabBar(indicatorWeight: 4.0,indicatorColor: Colors.white, controller: controller, tabs: <Tab>[
                new Tab(
                  text: 'Gruppen',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                ),
                new Tab(
                  text: 'Chats',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble),
                ),
                new Tab(
                  text: 'Einstellungen',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                )
              ]))),
          body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
            new first.GroupsOverview(),
            new second.ChatsOverview(),
            new third.Settings()
          ])),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To Switch between tabs, you don't Need Navigator.

As you have defined -  `TabController`

```
TabController controller;

@override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }
```

You can Simply call  - `controller.animateTo` method like - `controller.animateTo(2, curve: ElasticInCurve());` from anywhere to go to third tab & likewise to other tab.

**UPDATE:**
If you have different class defined for TabBar View - then need to pass controller with class constructors.

```
body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
          GroupsOverview(controller), // Pass the controller
          ChatsOverview(controller), // Pass the controller
          Settings(controller) // Pass the controller
        ])

class GroupsOverview extends StatelessWidget {
  TabController controller;  // ADD THIS

  GroupsOverview(this.controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.animateTo(1);
        },
        child: Text('Goto Chats'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatsOverview extends StatelessWidget {
  TabController controller;  // ADD THIS

  ChatsOverview(this.controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            controller.animateTo(2);
          },
          child: Text('Goto Einstellungen')),
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  TabController controller;  // ADD THIS
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            controller.animateTo(0);
          },
          child: Text('Goto Gruppen')),
    );
  }

  Settings(this.controller);
}
```

Comment: Let's say I am in a completely different class in another part of the app: Startpage -> Tap1, Tap2, Tap3; but I am in Tap1 -> User Profile -> [New Scaffold with a button]. How do I get to Tap2 when I am clicking on the button? Any chance I overwrite iOS automatic swipe-back gestures to also get to tap 2?

Comment: @user3532201 - pass the controller to the class with class constructors, ANSWER UPDATED

Comment: Thanks for the example. It works great as you have shown. But I have the issue, that I have a process of 4 steps (screens) where a group is created, each is a different class and linked via navigator.push into each other. Now I want to get from screen 4 to StartScreen tab 2. Even though I pass the textController via contractors, animated.to shows no effect.

Comment: In Case of navigator.push - On screen4 you need to do `navigator.popuntil` then after navigator.push in tab1 add command animate.to. add word `await` in front of `navigator.push`  in tab1 so it wait for .pop

Answer (score 2):

**To Go to the specific Tab in another page then you need to pass index of that tab.**

one screen to `TabBar` screen:

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabBarScreen(tabSelected: 1))
    );
},
```

and in `TabBar` Screen:

```
int tabSelected;
TabController _controller;
_TabBarScreenState(this.tabSelected);
  
@override
void initState() {
  print("Tab Selected ==== $tabSelected");
  _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  _controller.index = tabSelected;
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: kBackgroundGray,
    body: DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: tabSelected,
      length: 2,
    ),
  );
}
```

*in this screen i have only two tabs and this code is opening 2nd tab*